# Trying to format given to a function to create a string to generate an SQL statement

Tags: sql, ruby, hash, orm, symbols

I am currently trying to write a function that will take either one or two arguments and convert them to one string that can be passed and turned into an SQL statement.

the data types used can either be

1. a string
2. a symbol
3. a hash

and any combination of the three as in these examples,
a symbol and a hash,
`Entry.order(:name, phone_number: :desc)` that should yield, `"name, phone_number desc"`

two hashes, 
`Entry.order(name: :asc, phone_number: :desc)` that should yield, `"name asc, phone_number desc"`
this one is giving me the most trouble as the compiler reckognizes the both arguments as one hash.

one string
`Entry.order("name ASC, phone_number DESC")`  that should yield, `"name ASC, phone_number DESC"`

this is what I have written so far that works on some cases, but in particular I am quite stumped as ho to approach the second example. I have an block of code that converts a string into an SQL statement in my home codebase but am not including it here as it just gets in the way of the problem.

```
def order( * args)
  final_array = []

  args.each do |x |
    if x.class == String
      final_array << x
    elsif x.class == Hash#
      if x.to_s.include ? ","#
        puts "hit"#
      end
      x = x.to_s
      x = x.gsub(/{:/, '')
        x = x.gsub(/=>:/, ', ')
        x = x.gsub(/}/, '')
        puts x
        final_array << x
      elsif x.class == Symbol
        x = x.to_s
        final_array << x
      end

    end
    puts args.count
    if args.count > 1
      final_array = args.join(", ")
    else
      final_array = args.first.to_s
    end
    puts final_array

  end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel. Try using ActiveRecord, or at least, look into its source code and learn form it.

Comment: the original question from the assignment is "Entries currently have an arbitrary order. Add `.order` methods to modify and sort records."  

<br>

and I'm not using ActiveRecord record because i'm doing an assignment to learn about the underlying structures of databases. Believe me if I could use ActiveRecord, I would. i'll definitely look into the source code.

Comment: If you have a method with two hash arguments you need to add the hash braces when you call it to remove the ambiguity: `Entry.order({name: :asc}, {phone_number: :desc})`. I'm not sure if this solves your issue but it's worth taking note of. Anyway, using multiple hashes as parameters is probably unnecessary since you can use a single hash and iterate through the key-vals.